# How define instance Monad Writer with custom data type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, ghci, writer-monad

I have module:

```
module Writer where

import Prelude hiding (Monad, (>>=), return, (=<<))
main = putStrLn "hello"

class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a ->  (a -> m b) -> m b
  (=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
  (=<<) = flip (>>=)

data Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) } deriving Show

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where
  return x = Writer $ (x, mempty)
  m >>= k  = let
             (b, w1) = runWriter m
             Writer (a, w2) = k b
             in Writer (a, (w1 `mappend` w2))

writer :: (a, w) -> Writer w a
writer = Writer

instance (Semigroup a, Num a) => Monoid (Foo a) where
 mempty = Foo 0
 mappend (Foo v1) (Foo v2) = Foo (v1 + v2)

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Foo a) where
  (Foo v1) <> (Foo v2) = Foo (v1 <> v2)

instance Semigroup Integer where
  a1 <> a2 = a1 + a2


tell :: Monoid w => w -> Writer w ()
tell w = writer ((), w)

data Foo a = Foo { getFoo :: a } deriving Show

type LoggerFooInt = Writer (Foo Integer) ()

logLine :: String -> Integer -> LoggerFooInt
logLine _ = tell . Foo

batchLog :: Writer (Foo Integer) ()
batchLog = do
  logLine "line1"   19450
  logLine "line2"     760
  logLine "line3"     218
```

I tried to write `batchLog` function but compiler said:

```
Writer.hs:46:3: error:
    • No instance for (GHC.Base.Monad (Writer (Foo Integer)))
        arising from a do statement
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: logLine "line1" 19450
      In the expression:
        do logLine "line1" 19450
           logLine "line2" 760
           logLine "line3" 218
      In an equation for ‘batchLog’:
          batchLog
            = do logLine "line1" 19450
                 logLine "line2" 760
                 logLine "line3" 218
   |
46 |   logLine "line1"   19450
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

So, why I need to define any Monads else. I have already `instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w)` and `instance (Semigroup a, Num a) => Monoid (Foo a)` and `instance Semigroup Integer`. Why it's not enough? Without `batchLog` function module compiles.

> GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/

**UPDATE:** 
I tried to rewrite without do notation, and after a while I can do that and it compiles, but still can't understand, why another code, compiles with my own Monad and with do notation:

```
module MaybeMonad
import Prelude hiding (Monad, (>>=), return, (=<<))
import Control.Monad (ap, liftM)
import Data.Char

main = putStrLn "hello"

class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a ->  (a -> m b) -> m b
  (=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b


instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    (>>=) Nothing _ = Nothing
    (>>=) (Just x) k = k x
    (=<<) = flip (>>=)

data Token = Number Int | Plus | Minus | LeftBrace | RightBrace
    deriving (Eq, Show)

asToken :: String -> Maybe Token
asToken "+" = Just(Plus)
asToken "-" = Just(Minus)
asToken "(" = Just(LeftBrace)
asToken ")" = Just(RightBrace)
asToken str | all isDigit str = Just $ Number $ read str
asToken _ = Nothing

tokenize :: String -> Maybe [Token]
tokenize x = foldr (\word maybeTokens -> do
  token <- asToken word
  tokens <- maybeTokens
  return $ token : tokens) (return []) $ words x
```

**Correct example:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
module Writer where

import Prelude hiding (Monad, (>>=), return, (=<<), (>>))

class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a ->  (a -> m b) -> m b
  (=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
  (=<<) = flip (>>=)
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b

data Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) } deriving Show

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where
  return x = Writer $ (x, mempty)
  m >>= k  = let
             (b, w1) = runWriter m
             Writer (a, w2) = k b
             in Writer (a, (w1 `mappend` w2))
  ma >> mb = let
              (_, w1) = runWriter ma
              (vb, w2) = runWriter mb
             in Writer(vb, (w1 `mappend` w2))

writer :: (a, w) -> Writer w a
writer = Writer

instance (Semigroup a, Num a) => Monoid (Foo a) where
 mempty = Foo 0
 mappend (Foo v1) (Foo v2) = Foo (v1 + v2)

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Foo a) where
  (Foo v1) <> (Foo v2) = Foo (v1 <> v2)

instance Semigroup Integer where
  a1 <> a2 = a1 + a2


tell :: Monoid w => w -> Writer w ()
tell w = writer ((), w)

data Foo a = Foo { getFoo :: a } deriving Show

logLine :: String -> Integer -> Writer (Foo Integer) ()
logLine _ = tell . Foo

batchLog :: Writer (Foo Integer) ()
batchLog = do
  logLine "line1"   19450
  logLine "line2"     760
  logLine "line3"     218
```

after adding RebindableSyntax and hiding (>>) operator and adding my own realization it compiles and works properly.

Comment: I think it's because you've hidden the standard `Monad` class in `Prelude` and substituted it with your own. `do` notation is a special syntactic sugar which, I assume, only applies to "the" `Monad` class, not an arbitrary one that another module has called by the same name, and even if the definition happens to coincide.

Comment: Try enable `RebindableSyntax`

Comment: @RobinZigmond maybe you are right, but I have case then I use do notation with my own monad class, see to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @freestyle's comment, do-notation by design always uses the `Monad` class from `Prelude`, even if you have your own `Monad` class defined.  The [`RebindableSyntax`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-RebindableSyntax) extension can be enabled to make do-notation use whatever `Monad` class (or more specifically, whatever `>>=`, `>>`, and `fail` functions) are currently in scope.

This also affects a bunch of other rebindable syntax.  See the link above for a list, and make sure you aren't overriding additional syntax you don't intend to.

Also, `RebindableSyntax` implies `NoImplicitPrelude`, but that should be fine since you already have an `import Prelude` statement.

*UPDATE:*  However, it's important to make sure you've hidden **ALL** the applicable `Prelude` syntax, or you may find yourself unintentionally using the `Monad` class from `Prelude`, even if you didn't want to.  In your definition of:

```
batchLog :: Writer (Foo Integer) ()
batchLog = do
  logLine "line1"   19450
  logLine "line2"     760
  logLine "line3"     218
```

the do-block is desugared into:

```
batchLog = logLine "line1" 19450 >> logLine "line2" 760 >> ...
```

And, where is `(>>)` defined?  In `Prelude`, of course.  You will need to hide that as well, and provide your own definition, either in your custom `Monad` class or as a standalone function.  After making the following modifications to your first code block, the do-block type checks correctly, and `runWriter batchLog` appears to work fine:

```
import Prelude hiding (..., (>>), ...)

(>>) :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m b
act1 >> act2 = act1 >>= \_ -> act2
```